# Combining IF NOT ISNULL THEN ELSE Formulas (Crystal Reports)

Tags: crystal-reports, isnull

The following statements work independently of each other.However, I am struggling to combine them.

```
 IF NOT ISNULL({imlsmst_sql.hold_rsn}) 

 THEN CRYELLOW ELSE CRNOCOLOR

 IF NOT ISNULL ({@Hold_Desc}) 

 THEN CRYELLOW ELSE CRNOCOLOR
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND`:

```
IF NOT ISNULL({imlsmst_sql.hold_rsn}) AND NOT ISNULL ({@Hold_Desc}) THEN 
    CRYELLOW
ELSE
    CRNOCOLOR
```